# Does this system of equations have a solution?

Tags: digital-communications, linear-algebra

My heuristic approaches to find a solution for the following system of equations have failed so far. Does a solution exist?

$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_k & 0 \\
   a_{k-1} & a_k \\
   0 & a_{k-1}
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   g_{k-1} \\
   g_k
  \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.5 \\
   0\\
   0.5
  \end{array} } \right]+\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   d_{k-2} \\
   0\\
   d_k
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
such that $\{a_k\}$ are known data symbols with equal probability, chosen from L equidistant values. Unknown $\{g_k\}$ and $\{d_k\}$ are to be found such that $E\{d_k\} = E\{d_{k-2}\}=0$.

Comment: Please write the recurrence relation in matrix form.

Comment: Where did you get such model that you need to estimate the error value?